# How to override Eq, Show in records in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I would like to be able to override the default definitions for Eq and Show for records in Haskell. For example, suppose I want to define an ordered pair to be equal if the first entry is equal. But when I write this:

```
data Two = Two {a::Int, b::Int}

instance Eq Two where
x == y = ((a x) == (a y))
```

Haskell complains

```
Ambiguous occurrence `=='
It could refer to either `TestOverride.==',
                         defined at TestOverride.hs:15:3
                      or `Prelude.==',
                         imported from `Prelude' at TestOverride.hs:7:8-19
                         (and originally defined in `GHC.Classes')
```

What's the fix?

Comment: Move your cursor to the left of `x == y`. Press space two times. Reload/Recompile. Marvel.

Comment: Note that indentation matters in haskell. It doesn't matter quite as much as in Python, still indentation errors are among the most common for beginners.

Comment: @Cubic Care to write that as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your indentation is broken. Implementations of class functions must be indented at least one space or tab to the right of the instance keyword, so your instance should look like this:

```
instance Eq Two where
  x == y = ((a x) == (a y))
```

Note that this is true for other keywords that start "blocks" (like `do`, `where` etc) as well.

Comment: `class` doesn't start a block, the `where` after it does. The standard block starters are just four: `do`, `let`, `where` and `of`.  GHC extensions add more, though.

Comment: k, fixed. I meant that the whole class definition thing starts a block, but that's not what I wrote.